# How to express a BETWEEN statement in SQL when running query from a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather large statement that I've built up using an @SQL variable and then running the query from the variable at the end of the statement. This works fine except for when inserting a date into one of the parameters.

The query then returns no data and come back with an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The SQL I currently have is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVisitListFiltered]
    @sitekey int,
    @VisitNo int = NULL,
    @DNS varchar(max) = NULL,
    @SessionStarted varchar(15) = '01/01/1900',
    @Page varchar(max) = NULL,
    @SecondsOnSite int = NULL,
    @SecondsOnSiteRange int = NULL,
    @Pages int = NULL,
    @Cost int = NULL,
    @City varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Country varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Keywords varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Referrer varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
        SET @SecondsOnSiteRange = 
        CASE @SecondsOnSiteRange 
        WHEN 1 THEN '='
        WHEN 2 THEN '>'
        WHEN 3 THEN '<'
        ELSE NULL
        END

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @SQLParams NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @SQL = N'
            SELECT VKey,
                  VisitIP,
                  SiteKey,
                  Alert,
                  AlertNo,
                  VisitNo,
                  Invited,
                  Chatted,
                  Prospect,
                  Customer,
                  HackRaised,
                  Spider,
                  Cost,
                  Revenue,
                  Visits,
                  FirstDate,
                  TotalCost,
                  TotalRevenue,
                  OperatingSystem,
                  Browser,
                  SearchEngine,
                  Referrer,
                  Keywords,
                  ReferrerQuery,
                  Name,
                  Email,
                  Company,
                  Telephone,
                  Fax,
                  Street,
                  City,
                  Zip,
                  Country,
                  Web,
                  Organization,
                  CRMID,
                  Notes,
                  DNS,
                  Region,
                  FirstAlert,
                  FirstVisitReferrer,
                  ProspectTypes,
                  VisitDate,
                  SecondsOnSite,
                  Page
            FROM dbo.VisitDetail
            WHERE SiteKey = @p0';

        IF NULLIF(@VisitNo, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                   SET @SQL += N' AND VisitNo = @p1';
        IF NULLIF(@DNS, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                       SET @SQL += N' AND DNS = @p2';
        IF NULLIF(@SessionStarted, '01/01/1900') IS NOT NULL                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND VisitDate between @p3 and @p3 23:59:59';
        IF NULLIF(@Page, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND Page = @p4';
        IF NULLIF(@SecondsOnSite, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(@SecondsOnSiteRange, '') IS NOT NULL             SET @SQL += N' AND SecondsOnSite' + '@p12' + '@p5';
        IF NULLIF(@Pages, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                     SET @SQL += N' AND PagesSeen = @p6';
        IF NULLIF(@Cost, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND Cost = @p7';
        IF NULLIF(@City, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND City = @p8';
        IF NULLIF(@Country, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                   SET @SQL += N' AND Country = @p9';
        IF NULLIF(@Keywords, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND Keywords = @p10';
        IF NULLIF(@Referrer, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND ReferrerQuery = @p11';

        SET @SQLParams = N'
              @p0 INT
            , @p1 INT
            , @p2 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p3 VARCHAR(15)
            , @p4 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p5 INT
            , @p6 INT
            , @p7 INT
            , @p8 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p9 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p10 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p11 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p12 VARCHAR(10)';


        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
            , @SQLParams
            , @p0 = @SiteKey
            , @p1 = @VisitNo
            , @p2 = @DNS
            , @p3 = @SessionStarted
            , @p4 = @Page
            , @p5 = @SecondsOnSite
            , @p6 = @Pages
            , @p7 = @Cost
            , @p8 = @City
            , @p9 = @Country
            , @p10 = @Keywords
            , @p11 = @Referrer
            , @p12 = @SecondsOnSiteRange;


    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

I know the problem lies somewhere in this area:

```
IF NULLIF(@SessionStarted, '01/01/1900') IS NOT NULL 
SET @SQL += N' AND VisitDate between @p3 and @p3 23:59:59';
```

But I'm not sure how to fix it - can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: when you print your stored procedure you will see some syntax problem here `AND VisitDate between '09/03/2015' and '09/03//2015' 23:59:59'` which is not valid syntax

Comment: Ugh, [don't use between for this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). Also read [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has already been pointed out that `@SessionStarted` is a `VARCHAR` when it should be a date. And that your final SQL is malformed, and no more valid than:

```
DECLARE @p3 DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT Test = @p3 '23:59:59';
```

Which gives:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Incorrect syntax near '23:59:59'.

But I want to stress another point:

**DON'T USE BETWEEN LIKE THIS**

You are trying to construct a statement like:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2015-09-03'  AND '2015-09-03 23:59:59'
```

But what about if `Date` is '2015-09-03 23:59:59.5' - Do you really want this to be excluded? The best practice is to use an open ended range:

```
WHERE Date >= '2015-09-03'
AND Date < '2015-09-04'
```

Pretty much the same, but covers the entire day, not just most of it. SO your exact statement should probably be:

```
IF NULLIF(@SessionStarted, '01/01/1900') IS NOT NULL 
    SET @SQL += N' AND VisitDate >= @p3 AND VisitDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @p3)';
```

Aaron Bertrand has written a [great article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on this for further reading.

So in summary, a partial fix would be to use the concatenatation operator `+`:

```
DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(50) = '03/09/2015';
SELECT Test = @p3 + ' 23:59:59';
```

A better fix would be to convert to the right datatype:

```
DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(50) = '03/09/2015';
SELECT Test = CONVERT(DATETIME, @p3 + ' 23:59:59');
```

Even better would be to use a culture invariant date format, so it is clear whether you mean 3rd September or 9th March:

```
DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(50) = '20150903';
SELECT Test = CONVERT(DATETIME, @p3 + ' 23:59:59');
```

Even better still would be to use the correct datatype in the first place:

```
DECLARE @p3 DATETIME = '20150903';
SELECT Test = @p3 + '23:59:59';
```

And better yet, would be to use an open ended date range as described above.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `sessionstarted` to be a character rather than a date.   I imagine that this is the root cause of your problem.

Change the type to a date.  I would also recommend that you use ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format for the date, rather than a culture-specific format.

Comment: Worth noting that the ISO Standard is culture-specific in SQL Server when using `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this bit 
    @p3 23:59:59';

You are trying to concatenate a string value to a date. What you need to do is a an addition (DATEADD) to the date held in @p3, and use that as another parameter

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use the correct data type. In your case `@SessionStarted` should be declared as `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR`.

After you do that, instead of adding `23:59:59` to your date field to get records occurring on that day, you should use this instead:

```
SET @SQL += N' AND VisitDate >= @p3 AND VisitDate < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @p3)'
```